# Easier way of deleting rows in pandas dataframe based on condition from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, iteration

Suppose I have two dataframes

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"A" : [1,1,2,5],
             "B" : [1,1,4,5],
             "C" : ["Adam","Bella","Charlie","Dan"]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({"A" : [1,1,3,5],
             "B" : [1,3,6,5]})
```

and I want to delete the rows in `df1` that have the same values of `A` and `B` with `df2`

I do this by

```
for i, row_1 in df1.iterrows():

    for j, row_2 in df2.iterrows():
        
        if row_1["A"] == row_2["A"] and row_1["B"] == row_2["B"]:
            index = i
            df1.drop([index], axis=0, inplace=False)
```

which resulted in, as intended

```
    A   B   C
2   2   4   Charlie
```

I was wondering if there was a much easier/faster way to do this especially if the data frame is large then it is not ideal to iterate over all the rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `left-merge` with the `indicator` parameter to flag the rows that match; then `query` to filter the rows that come only from `df1`:

```
out = df1.merge(df2, how='left', indicator=True).query('_merge=="left_only"').drop(columns=['_merge'])
```

Output:

```
   A  B        C
2  2  4  Charlie
```

Comment: How does the above code satisfy this condition ``row_1["A"] == row_2["A"] and row_1["B"] == row_2["B"]``

Comment: @PandaPandas it merges on the common columns (in this case `A` and `B`); i.e. it matches the `A` and `B` values in `df1` with the `A` and `B` values in `df2`

Comment: How would this work if the columns for the two dataframe did not share the same strings

Comment: @PandaPandas do you mean common column names? because columns don't contain strings. If there are no common column names, you'll have to specify which columns to merge on. So `df1.merge(df2, how='left', left_on=['A','B'], right_on=['AA','BB'], indicator=True)` etc.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way:

```
df1.loc[~df1.set_index(['A','B']).index.isin(df2.to_records(index=False).tolist())]
```

Comment: How would this work if the columns for the two dataframe did not share the same strings

Answer (score 0):

```
#!pip install siuba
from siuba import anti_join

anti_join(df1, df2, on = ['A', 'B'])

   A  B        C
2  2  4  Charlie
```

if you want to `anti_join` on all shared columns:

```
anti_join(df1, df2)
 
   A  B        C
2  2  4  Charlie
```

Comment: How would this work if the columns for the two dataframe did not share the same strings

Comment: @PandaPandas will just give an empty dataframe